# Pip could not find a version that satisfies the requirement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, wxpython

I'm having problems with installing a package using pip. I tried :

```
pip install wx
```

Causing these errors :

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wx (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for wx
```

I checked if pip was up to date which was the case. I'm on Python 3.10.6

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you looking for [the `wxPython` package](https://pypi.org/project/wxPython/)? Note that you may need to [build from source](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/wxPython-4.2.0/README.rst).

Comment: Yes. i`ll try build

Comment: If you're on Linux take a gander at https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify an older version of wx, or if there is documentation on the package, read the requirements, maybe you need an older or newer version of python. Try also
`pip install wxPython` or https://pypi.org/project/wxPython/

Comment: [There is no `wx` package on PyPI](https://pypi.org/search/?q=wx)

Comment: wxPython Phoenix is the latest version of wxPython. Or am I being stupid

Comment: All I'm saying is there's no `wx` package to install. If your recommendation is to use an older version of `wx`, that doens't help much.